# TabLayout text is highlighted

Tags: android, android-layout

My styles are as follows

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <!--for globalApp-->
        <item name="android:background">@color/gray50</item>
        <!--for fab-->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/gray900</item>

        <!--for tabLayout-->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray50</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/gray400</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/deepOrangeA400</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextAppearance.Design.Tab</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextAppearance.Design.Tab" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

and my layout is as follows

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.app.form.HomeActivity"
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/select_form_type" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

select_form_type.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/select_form_tab"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
/>
```

When I run the app my tab text is highlighted for some reason. Here is how my text looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7WM0.jpg
http://postimg.org/image/j335xzlql/

How can I remove the text highlight?
Also is this the best way to organize styles?

Comment: **1)** Your comments may say some styles apply to certain widgets, the truth is that everything in the `AppTheme` style applies to the whole activity. Google "ThemeOverlay" and use `android:theme` attribute to override theme for certain widgets. **2)** You're overriding appcompat-v7 style `Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout`. Common practice would be to extend `Widget.Design.TabLayout` and apply this new style via `style` attribute on the widget.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Eugen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes away after I remove @color/gray50
from my theme.

Is there any way to specify the background color in the theme and then reference that color in specific style tags?

Something like :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/gray900</item>
        <item name="colorBackground">@color/gray50</item>  -----X
    </style>

and then use it like:
<style name="MyCustomStype" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:textColor">?colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:background">?colorBackground</item>
    </style>
```

When I do this I get an error, attribute color background doesnot exist.

Comment: `andorid:background` is a *style* attribute. If you define it in a *theme* every widget will have this background by default. You were looking for `android:windowBackground`.